# OrientDB Javadocs for offline use download location?

Tags: orientdb

The OrientDB javadoc reference can be found at http://orientdb.com/javadoc/2.2.x/, but I have been unsuccessful in locating the API reference docs in a downloadable form as a ZIP of the HTML or a PDF.

I've tried pulling the [latest source](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb) down from github but Maven hasn't been playing nice with me when I've tried to build it using:

```
$ mvn javadoc:javadoc
```

If there's a better command line option to make it build an offline copy of the docs, I can make another attempt.

It would be fantastic if the javadocs were available for download for offline use... if it is available can someone provide the link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate the Javadoc locally, clone the repository and execute from the root of the project: `mvn javadoc:aggregate`. The complete html will be generated on `./target/site/apidocs/`

If you need to have the Javadoc available in the IDE (idea, eclipse), `mvn dependency:resolve -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true` will download sources and Javadoc jars.

And of course Javadoc jars are available on maven central:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-core/2.2.13/

Comment: Thanks.  Sadly, maven still won't build for me without errors.  I suspect it's our corporate firewall... I thought the OrientDB guys had a downloadable .zip of the javadocs that were already compiled into .html or something once upon a time...  I've been using Netbeans and it's not been overly kind with importing javadocs for the OrientDB APIs.  It'd be nice to have that, but something which is searchable is also desirable since I'm new to the OrientDB API ecosystem.

Comment: I've never used NetBeans, but Eclipse and Intellij-IDEA, when importing a maven project, are able to download sources and javadoc jars. I can't believe that NB isn't able to do that

Comment: It probably can, I'm just new to java.  I was able to get it to build the HTML docs, but I had to do it at home.  That indicates to me that our corporate firewall / proxy does not play nice with Maven when it wants to pull stuff in.  From the replies on this thread, it sounds like the OrientDB guys assume that all environments have access to the Internet and can just browse the apidocs online -or- they have a build environment that will allow OrientDB to build from source to generate the docs.  I don't have either of those luxuries.  Would be nice if they'd host a downloadable apidocs zip ;)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you have a bad internet connection, but  build systems such as maven and gradle on java side and on every other language (grunt, rake) need a connection to the internet in some ways. They all rely on central artifacts repositories (maven central, npm  etc.). BTW, does maven report errors when you type on the command line  `mvn dependency:resolve -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the docs for offline use here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-Manual.pdf

Javadoc is available in OrientDB: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to clarify...  I'm interested in finding an *offline* copy of the javadocs in either HTML or PDF.  So far the only place I can find them is at http://orientdb.com/javadoc/2.2.x

Comment: you can clone the github project and so you will have all javadoc offline on your pc

Comment: Is there Javadoc already compiled into a HTML or PDF format in the github repo, or does the github site contain _only_ the source code?  I have downloaded the source but cannot locate the API docs and I have been unsuccessful in compiling it on my workstation (see notes in question for how I'm attempting this).